# Bootstrap 3 glyphicons not showing until I zoom in and out

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

For one reason or another, glyphicons are not loading properly on my Chrome or Firefox, however it seems they work just fine on IE (not tested too many times, maybe just lucky).

The glyphicons are not showing on my page until I zoom in/out. Even zooming in or out by 10% makes them appear and when I come back to normal size (100%) they are still there. However, I cant see them when the page is first loaded.

Im testing the following template from Bootstrap page :

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/

All I did was I've replaced the 140x140 heading images with glyphicons, and resized them to 90 px with the simple example code like this :

```
span.glyphicon-globe {
font-size: 80px;
color: #EA8A46;
}
```

Here's how I use them :

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span>
  <h2>Test</h2>
  <p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-warning" href="#" role="button">więcej &raquo;</a></p>
</div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  <h2>Test 2</h2>
  <p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-warning" href="#" role="button">więcej &raquo;</a></p>
</div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
  <h2>Test 3</h2>
  <p>Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
  <p><a class="btn btn-warning" href="#" role="button">więcej &raquo;</a></p>
</div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
```

There's a note on the template like this :

`Note: If you're viewing this page via a file:// URL, the "next" and "previous" Glyphicon buttons on the left and right might not load/display properly due to web browser security rules.`

However I'm not using it with a `file://`. The issue is there on localhost AND live server. I didn't use customizer on bootstrap page, the fonts are from the standard .zip file.

If you need more code, I will happily supply it.

EDIT:
Just did more testing with new installation of IE and Firefox and everything works fine. Could it be just Chrome ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if font face is referred correctly. This was an issue noticed when downloading via the customized download option on bootstrap.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url('Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded- opentype'), url('Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('Content/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons-halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

If not, you can also try using cdn. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aQrPd/1/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've tried both things and it still doesn't help in Chrome. I've reinstalled the browser, but the issue is still there. Everything is still fine on IE and Firefox. In my file the url was like `../fonts/` and I've put the proper link to those files on the live server. It wokrs just fine for the Firefox and IE, but still not for Chrome. Weird bug...

Comment: Can you check in the console if there are any errors mentioned. You'd have to right click on the page and click inspect element and then console.

Comment: Make sure to clear/disable your browser cache (it might have survived the reinstall). I've often had problems with fonts not loading, or wrong font being loaded, which went away after purging cache.

Have you tried it problem persist with fonts like Icomoon or FontAwesome? Another thing you could do is to change the font family name, and its reference in CSS.